# Hard Bricked Verizon SCH-I545 Galaxy S4

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, unbricking

I got a Verizon SCH-I545 Galaxy S4 and tried to unlock the bootloader and accidentally hard bricked it. I can't even go in to download mode or recovery mode either. Is there a way I would be able to fix it? I heard that using a USB Jig would fix it. Are there any other way to fix this issue?

I'm not sure if this would help but some additional information:

Baseband Version: I545VRUFNC5
Kernel Version: 3.4.0
Android Version: 4.4.2
New Phone.

I rooted using towelroot. I remember disabling Knox while rooting.

Comment: If there is absolutely no way to get into recovery or download or boot the device then you will have to go to a repair centre or if you know someone who owns and can use a JTAG you might be able to do something. To be honest, if it's completely hardbricked you'll need specialist help.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up calling Verizon saying that I wasn't able to turn on my phone since it was "actually not turning on." Eventually I was able to change my hard-bricked phone to a new one. Gonna go to the store today or tomorrow. Thanks for the information though!